# Cross-referenced equation never becomes defined

Tags: equations, cross-referencing

I have a strange problem with cross-referencing my equations:
no matter how often I run pdflatex they stay undefined.
Other references do get resolved.

Is there something wrong with the way I label my equation? Pdflatex does
not complain about it (other than reporting it is undefined when
trying to reference it).

Edit: As requested below I made a minimal working example. From this I learned that the problem seems to be a conflict between the amsmath and ntheorem packages. Not including one of these solves the problem.

Consider for example the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[thmmarks]{ntheorem}

\begin{document}

\section{My Section}
\label{sec:MySection}

\begin{equation} \label{eq:MyEquation}
a = b
\end{equation}

Reference my section \ref{sec:MySection}.
Reference my equation \ref{eq:MyEquation}.

\end{document}
```

Which is rendered as:

[image: Not working]

Comment: This is not a complete example. The easiest way to make it a complete document is to add `\documentclass{article}` and `\begin{document}` at the beginning, and `\end{document}` at the end. If you do that, do you still get a strange result? If not, what do you have to add from your original document to make a complete example to show the problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.  Please complete you code snippet to a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).  As it stands when placed a simple document it does not produce the behaviour you describe.

Comment: If I add an appropriate `\documentclass` declaration and the `document` environment, I get no problem. My advice is “look for a typo” in the label name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the additional option `amsmath` for `ntheorem`, see "3.2.1 amsmath" of `ntheorem`'s [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/ntheorem/ntheorem.pdf).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[thmmarks,amsmath]{ntheorem}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{4}
\section{My Section}
\label{sec:MySection}

\begin{equation} \label{eq:MyEquation}
a = b
\end{equation}

Reference my section \ref{sec:MySection}.
Reference my equation \ref{eq:MyEquation}.

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: And a useful further information is, that `amsmath` also provides `\eqref` to reference equations, i.e. it surrounds the number with brackets like `(1)`.